# ImportError: cannot import name 'PowerTransformer'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Whenever I try to run the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
ptt = PowerTransformer()
plt.plot(ptt.fit(df))
```

This error appears:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PowerTransformer'
```

Current version of my scikit-learn is 0.19.1

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Upgrade your sklearn to a latest version. I am not sure 0.19.1 have Power transformer.

Comment: PowerTransformer might be misspelled or it could be missing

Comment: There is no error in  scikit-learn (0.20.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting error because in the sklearn version you use `PowerTransformer` is not present.

It is only added in version 0.20.0. You can see the change log of version 0.20.0 for more details.

To solve the issue upgrade your sklearn version.

If you are on conda you can do

`conda update scikit-learn`

to upgrade your sklearn

Comment: @hyTuev Nice to hear it helped